# register_form, custom field not submitted on first try

Tags: custom-field, user-registration

I seem to have a problem with a custom field on the [register form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form) (used in conjunction with WooCommerce)

```
    function my_account_send_form_post_data( ) {

        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $firstname = $_POST["billing_first_name"];
        $lastname = $_POST["billing_last_name"];

        $api = $this->get_api();
        if ( ! $api ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['mailchimp-subscribe'] ) && 'yes' == $_POST['mailchimp-subscribe'] ) {
            $list_id = $this->get_option( 'wc_mailchimp_list_id' );

            $double_optin = $this->get_option( 'wc_mailchimp_double_optin' ) == 'yes';

            $api->my_account_subscribe_to_list( $list_id, $firstname, $lastname, $email);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to Mailchimp via account registration on my-account page
     * @param  string      $list_id   
     * @param  string      $firstname 
     * @param  string      $lastname  
     * @param  string      $email
    **/

    public function my_account_subscribe_to_list( $list_id, $firstname, $lastname, $email) 
    {

        $data = array(
            'id' => $list_id,
            'email' => array( 'email' => $email ),
            'merge_vars' => array(
                'FNAME' => $firstname,
                'LNAME' => $lastname,                   
            ),
            'double_optin' => false,
            'update_existing' => true,
        );

        $response = $this->perform_request( '/lists/subscribe.json', $data );

        $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        echo print_r($response, true);
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $response = json_decode( $response, true );
        echo print_r($response, true);
        if ( isset( $response['status'] ) && 'error' ==  $response['status'] ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

As you can see the `my_account_subscribe_to_list` handles the submission of the custom information and will `print_r` the response.

First attempt you try to register you will be registered to WordPress correctly but the custom data is never processed.

On second attempt registering an account using the same registration information as the first attempt. You will receive an error that the registration information is already in use (as suspected). But you will also receive the output of `$response` hence the custom field and data is being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for `register_form` is a mention of [user_register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) under hooks which is used to:

> This action hook allows you to access data for a new user immediately
>   after they are added to the database. The user id is passed to hook as
>   an argument.
>
> Typically, this hook is used for saving additional user meta passed by
>   custom registration forms.

changing `register_form` to `user_register` fixed the issue and let me do additional data handling when the registration is completing